# How to link multple string manipulation commands in bash?

Tags: bash

I have the follwing which creates a directory from a list of files:

```
for file in $(ls *.txt); do 
    folder=${file//.txt/ }; 
    folder=${folder//./'/'}; 
    folder=${folder//[[:space:]]/}; 
    mkdir -p $folder;
done
```

Can I link the 3 string manipulation commands that assign `folder` into one line?

I've tried several things with no success. Is it possible to use the `|` operator somehow?

Comment: No; you cannot chain parameter expansion operators within a single expansion.

Comment: agreed with above. And why do you care? If you're looking to reduce line count, then just join those assignments onto one line, i.e. `folder=..; folder=... ; folder-..`. You could probably put all of those manipulations into one `sed` command, but then you'd be creating a subprocess to execute it, and this will be slower and more inefficient than using the shell's built in paramter expansions. Good luck.

Comment: Unrelated hint: Replace `for file in $(ls *.txt)` with `for file in *.txt`. It's shorter and much safer.

Comment: If you really wanted, you could use `folder="$(sed 's,\.txt, ,g;s,\.,/,g;s,[[:space:]],,g' <<< "$file")"`, but there is no benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash cannot do this, but [Z Shell (zsh)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (which is very similar) can nest the replacements:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    folder=${${${file//.txt/ }//./'/'}//[[:space:]]/}; 
    mkdir -p $folder;
done
```

(You don't need to do `$(ls *.txt)` (parsing `ls` in this way is [dangerous](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs): you lose all spaces) since you can just give it `*.txt`, which properly handles spaces in filenames. This works in any POSIX shell.)